# What is the best Rest Assured alternative for Python API testing?

Tags: python, selenium, rest-assured, web-api-testing

In Java, we have Rest Assured for API testing. In python, what are the best possible alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best one is Requests - https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

[request](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library is used widely for api calls in python.
Talking about framework for testing, you can use [pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/) or [unittest](https://pypi.org/project/unittest2/)
where pytest is the most popular one.